# Getting error while Sqoop export, how can I find out the exact error?

Tags: export, sqoop

While doing sqoop export:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://ip-172-31-20-247/dbname --username uname --password pwd --table orders --export-dir /orders.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

```
18/11/10 16:18:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/11/10 16:19:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/11/10 16:19:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1537636876515_6580 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1537636876515_6580_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
18/11/10 16:19:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
        Job Counters 
                Failed map tasks=1
                Killed map tasks=3
                Launched map tasks=4
                Data-local map tasks=4
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=61530
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=20510
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=20510
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=31503360
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
18/11/10 16:19:01 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
18/11/10 16:19:01 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 17.1712 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
18/11/10 16:19:01 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
18/11/10 16:19:01 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export job failed!
18/11/10 16:19:01 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
```

How can I determine what the exact error is?

Comment: Need more detailed stack trace. Check for `yarn` container logs.

Comment: How to check for yarn container log

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats happening with your sqoop export job without having a look at file data and other details. I hope you are using the right delimiter and your file layout and table structure are in sync.

Could you please try below sqoop export script with your parameters changed.
Here I have sqoop data from hdfs file to sql server.

```
sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=EMP;" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--username userid \
-P \
--table sql_server_table_name \
--input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
--export-dir /hdfs path location of file/part-m-00000 \
--num-mappers 1 \
```

Let me know if it works for you. I have tested it couple of times and its working fine with no issues. my data is delimited by '|' so I have choose input fields terminated as '|'. you can choose depending on your data on hdfs.